# Android BroadcastReceiver in BlackBerry 10 Android Runtime

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, blackberry-10

I am trying to create an Android app in which contains a broadcastreceiver that will pick up on the SCREEN_OFF and USER_PRESENT events (lock and unlock events).

I have tried to research this and I had no luck finding any info.

My question is; will the Android Runtime on BlackBerry 10 support Android's BroadcastReceiver for the SCREEN_OFF and USER_PRESENT events?

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked.

Thank you!